# Keep UINavigationBar height with prefersStatusBarHidden

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, uistatusbar

At certain times in my app I am hiding the `UIStatusBar` on iOS 7.

```
-(UIStatusBarAnimation)preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimationFade;
}

-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    if (self.state == StateModal) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

However, this the y-origin of the view controller's `UINavigationBar`. It moves up since there is not `UIStatusBar` visible, but I would like to retain the height of the status bar, but makes it's content invisible.

Is this possible? I don't have to take iOS 6 into account, just iOS 7.

Comment: I'm currently facing the same issue. Did you find a solution or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can change current window windowLevel to UIWindowLevelStatusBar, when controller is appeared
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21158994/2035054